# Heroku rails blogger not processing login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, blogger

So I push my rails_blogger app to Heroku and it goes fine, I run rake db:migrate and it goes fine, but then when I try to login using the email and password I made, it doesn't let me login and just renders the login page again.
When I run webrick on my computer everything works fine with login, but when I access the app from the heroku URL in my browser, it won't let me login!
Also, it won't even show the articles on the main page that anyone should see, logged in or not.

I've looked all over various google search results to find the answer to this to no avail.

Can someone help me understand the problem here?

GitHub repo: https://github.com/ck626/project_rails_blogger

Heroku page: scary-goblin-6551.herokuapp.com

Comment: your local and heroku username and password won't be same. Sometime we forget that, double check that.

Comment: show us  `heroku logs` when you create new user of your blog app.

Comment: 2015-11-07T13:58:49.585199+00:00 app[web.1]:   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"���", "authenticity_token"=>"a87VeS3PsnywvDGKf2L7h8ofeEMBfIrqICQeGGMVvaH9B6ysqxxDowoZLOE7p0+B4dYXg9fEGPFCAhJ1UEpKCg==", "email"=>"admin@admin.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "commit"=>"Login"}
2015-11-07T13:58:49.607495+00:00 app[web.1]:   Author Load (4.1ms)  SELECT  "authors".* FROM "authors" WHERE "authors"."email" = 'admin@admin.com'  ORDER BY "authors"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
2015-11-07T13:58:49.617001+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 200 OK in 32ms (Views: 8.5ms | ActiveRecord: 16.4ms)

Comment: I used heroku logs --tail to get this log portion while actually on my herokuapp blogsite (scary-goblin-6551) trying to log in

Comment: Ok, i went to the "authors" route in the browser and it allowed me to make a new user. Thanks for the help!   If you could explain why that is, id appreciate it.  Does Heroku have a different database then my local app?

Comment: Can I put it as an answer as it worked out well?

Answer (score 0):

The database that you use at heroku are different from your local database, so you need to create authors separately on heroku and at your local development server. In Rails you can configure your database (what database to use at production and at development) at `config/database.yml`.

Another thing to note heroku does not support sqlite, you need to use pg instead.